# struts2 - multiple submit buttons with separate action classes

Tags: java, javascript, struts2

I need to call different action classes for different submit buttons in a single form and get the value of a dropdown in struts2.

example for a schools student page:

1. Submit Button 1: Show academic page
2. Submit Button 2: Show sports page
3. Submit Button 3: Show library page
   and so on.

I tried as follows but it does not work.

Code:

```
<s:submit value="academic" action="academic" />
<s:submit value="sports" action="sports" />
<s:submit value="library" action="library" />

Generated html code gets 
<input name="action:academic">
<input name="action:sports">
```

I am using `theme="simple"` in form tag.

I tried it by URL tag but the called action is not populating the dropdown fields value as roll no of student.

struts.xml:

`

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="academics" class="ViewAcademics" > 
        <result name="success">pages/ViewAcademics.jsp</result> 
    </action> 
    <action name="sports" class="ViewSports" > 
        <result name="success">pages/ViewSports.jsp</result> 
    </action> 
    <action name="library" class="ViewLibrary" > 
        <result name="success">pages/ViewLibrary.jsp</result> 
    </action>
</package>
```

`

JSP File:

```
<s:form name="inquiryForm" method="post" theme="simple" > 
   Select roll no : 
   <s:select style="width: 200px;" 
      list="#{'1':'Student 01', '2':'Student 02', '3':'Student 03', '4':'Student 04'}"
      id="projectName" 
      name="studentRollNo" 
      readonly="false" 
      headerKey="-1" 
      headerValue="--- Select ---" 
   /> 
   <s:submit cssClass="page" action="academics" value="academics" /> 
   <s:submit cssClass="page" name="sports" value="sports" /> 
   <s:submit cssClass="page" name="library" value="library" /> 
</s:form>
```

Comment: Show your action configurations.

Comment: in struts.xml I had mentioned actions in separate action tags

Comment: Could you post your `struts.xml` file and complete JSP form.

Comment: Put your code inside your question not in the comments.

Comment: Edit the question and put your WHOLE `struts.xml` file to it. BTW you have typo in your action name.

Answer (score 0):

Use `action` attribute in your submit declarations:

```
<s:submit cssClass="page" action="academics" value="academics" /> 
<s:submit cssClass="page" action="sports" value="sports" /> 
<s:submit cssClass="page" action="library" value="library" />
```

And all your actions should have variable `studentRollNo` with getters/setters.

Comment: I tried with this.
But generated html is like below code.
'<input type="submit" name="action:academic">'
And the flow gets some error.
Is this the one html that needs to be generated ???